# Using the knowledge that two arguments have the same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm learning TypeScript. In this example, I'm trying to write a generic function that I can use to compare either two numbers or two tuples of numbers. I've defined a type alias `Compare` for the allowed kinds of arguments:

```js
type Compare = number | [number, number]

function compare<T extends Compare>(a: T, b: T): number {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        let res = compare(a[0], b[0]);
        //                      ^^^^
        // TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of 
        // type '0' can't be used to index type 'Compare'.
        // Property '0' does not exist on type 'Compare'.
        
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
    } else {
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that the problem is that even after checking that argument `a` is an array, b is still inferred to be of type `Compare`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a very simple solution, also check if `b` is an array:
Typescript is smart enough to now understand that `a` and `b` are tuples.

```
if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {
  // ...

  // You could include an `else if` for the case that the function is passed only one tuple and one number
} else if (Array.isArray(a) || Array.isArray(b)) { 
  // I'm assuming this case should error  
  throw new TypeError("Mismatching types")
}
```

### Overloading

> **DO NOT USE UNLESS YOU ARE EXPERIENCED WITH TYPESCRIPT**

```
function compare(a: number, b: number): number
function compare(a: [number, number], b: [number, number]): number
function compare(a: any, b: any) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    return compare(a[0], b[0]);
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think overloading is an advanced concept for only experienced users. It's pretty basic.

Comment: Wait, was my question really this unclear!? I assumed that by adding the type argument `T` to the function that my intention would be clear to only allow _either_ two tuples _or_ two numbers to be passed to the function, so the check for `Array.isArray(a) || Array.isArray(b)` in your example is non-sensical for the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: To phrase it differently: I was asking for a compile-time check, but your solution is a runtime check.

Comment: @Feuermurmel the two parameters `a` and `b` are *independent of each other*. Your code does *not* say "they are *either* both `number` or both `[number, number]` but nothing else". It just says that *each* is one of these. So you can call `compare(1, [2, 3])` *or* `compare([1, 2], 3)` - [both are legal compile-time calls](https://tsplay.dev/wjQbkW). That's how generics work - they aren't fit for the purpose you use them. If you want to describe "I only accept both being numbers or both being tuples" you need an overload.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I have to admit, I'm coming from a functional programming background, where generics often behave very differently to OO languages, it's been a few years since I did any OO generics programming. Then, is there a functional difference between `function compare<T extends Compare>(a: T, b: T)` and `function compare(a: Compare, b: Compare)`? (assuming that the return type does not depend on `T`)

Comment: @Feuermurmel there is *some* difference. With generics, it's the caller who decides the generic argument. `T` is bounded to be a *subset* of `Compare`. So, for example, `compare<1>` is a valid call and then the only possible parameters would be `(1, 1)`. Or the call site might specify `compare<1 | 2 | 3>` or `compare<1 | [2, 3]>`. These calls will differ from just `compare(a: Compare, b: Compare)` where neither the caller nor the callee has any restriction. The generic variant will overlap with the non-generic only for `compare<Compare>`.

Comment: @Feuermurmel With that said, TS will try to infer the generic argument when not supplied. For some reason, it determines that `compare(1, [1, 2]);` is a `compare<1>` and when called with a mix of number and tuple seems to pick the type of `a` for the generic but `compare([2, 3], 1)` is also a `compare<1>` :  https://tsplay.dev/wglzlN Not sure what's happening there. Seems it tries to determine the subtype of the generic based on the parameters but IMO doesn't do it properly.

Comment: I'd accept your answer but the part before _Overloading_ is misleading, because it doesn't match the question (I'm asking for "a generic function that I can use to compare either two numbers or two tuples of numbers").

Comment: @Feuermurmel Sorry for the delay of response. If what you're looking for is a check only at compile-time, I'd say overloading is the way to go. I'll edit the answer for a more fleshed out version of the overloading section. As vlaz mentioned, `a` and `b` don't both have to be the same type (i.e. "a=tuple, b=number" is allowed), which is why I thought the runtime check was suitable.

Comment: @LearnforFun Yeah, I don't care about runtime! The thing is, while the code is compiling, I'm in front of the computer and can fix any issues that pop up. But while it is running, I'm mostly not!

Comment: @Feuermurmel I see. To conclude, I'll say the first solution does check on runtime, but it does also tell TS (in compile time) that `a` and `b` are both tuples. And the `or (||)` check that comes later is to make sure not only one of them is a tuple. I'll leave it there for other people if they see it as it is an easy and practical solution. If you want a solution that does not check on runtime at all, then you can use the overloading solution. I hope it helps