# How to type function that takes two arguments of same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This a follow-up to [Using the knowledge that two arguments have the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73360431/using-the-knowledge-that-two-arguments-have-the-same-type).

I have this function which can be called with two argument of the same type from a set of types. The set  contains every type which can be built from the type `number` and by creating pair-types from two other types in the set, e.g. `[number, number]`, `[number, [number, number]]`, `[[number, number], [number, number]]`, etc.:

```js
function plus(a: any, b: any): any {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return [plus(a[0], b[0]), plus(a[1], b[1])];
    } else {
        return a + b;
    }
}

plus(1, 2); // returns 3
plus([1, 2], [3, 4]); // returns [4, 6]
plus([1, [2, 3]], [10, [10, 10]]); // returns [11, [12, 13]]
```

The two types must be the same, so the following calls are not allowed:

```js
plus(1, [10, 10]])
plus([0, [1, 1]], [[0, 0], 1])
```

The return type of the function is always the same as the type of the arguments. **How do I type this function?**

I first tried to do this:

```js
type Plus = number | [Plus, Plus]

function plus<T extends Plus>(a: T, b: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return [plus(a[0], b[0]), plus(a[1], b[1])];
    } else {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

But of this doesn't work. Of course, nothing prevents, `T` from containing the type `number | [number, number]`. In an answer to the question above, it was suggested to add overloads to the function, but this also doesn't work because there are an infinite number of types.

I think the issue is that `Plus` itself is a type. In a language that supports *type classes*, I would solve this by creating a type class `Plus` (instead of a type) and then adding instances for `number` and tuples of instances of `Plus` to the type class. Then I can constrain `T` to `Plus` and avoid the problem. But I feel quite stuck here. **Is there anything equivalent to type classes in TypeScript?**

Comment: This one is definitely possible, but it's going to take some time for someone to make it work lol

Comment: [Well, this is step one of two: forcing parameters to be of the same type](https://tsplay.dev/mpLlpm). The next step, making sure that the provided type is not a union, is a little more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your problem.

```
type Increment<T extends unknown[]> = [...T, unknown]


export type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean;
// infers the input and prevents widening, e.g. [0,0,0] wont collapse to number[]
export type Narrow<A> =
  | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never)
  | (A extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? [Narrow<Head>, ...Narrow<Tail>] : never)
  | {
    [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Function ? A[K] : Narrow<A[K]>;
  };

// takes any number tuple structure e.g. [1,2,4,[1,3]] and replaces every specific number  with the number type [number,number,number,[number,number]] 
export type WideNumberTuple<A, Structure extends any[] = []> =
  A extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? WideNumberTuple<Tail, [...Structure, WideNumberTuple<Head>]> : A extends number ? number : Structure


// Checks if the provided tuple always followes this pattern type T = [number, T | number] <- this type is infinite so we can't use it for a type constraint
type Validate<Input, Output = Input, Depth extends unknown[] = []> =
  Input extends [infer Left, infer Right]
  ? Left extends number
  ? Right extends number | [number, [number, any] | number | (any[])]
  ? Validate<Right, Output, Increment<Depth>>
  // Prints an error msg when the pattern don't match
  : `Invalid Tuple item in source or target depth: ${Increment<Depth>["length"] extends number ? Increment<Depth>["length"] : ""}`
  : `Invalid Tuple item in source or target depth: ${Depth["length"]}` : Input

function plus<T>(
  // Narrows input eg [0, [3, 43]]
  a: Narrow<T>,
  // 1. Widens a to b = [number, [number, number]]
  // 2. Validates b -> no error msg was returned the structure is valid
  b: Validate<WideNumberTuple<T>> extends string
    ? Validate<T>
    : WideNumberTuple<T>
): T {
  throw Error("not implemented")
}


plus([0, [3, 43]], [1, [2, 3]])
plus([0, [3, 43]], [1, [2]]) // error Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
plus([0, [3, [43]]], [1, [2, [5, 2]]]) // error type '"Invalid Tuple item in source or target depth 2"'
plus([[3, [4, 4, 4]]], [1, [3, [4, 4]]]) // error
```